# when and where Sanitizing and Escaping in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, escaping

I was reading about Sanitizing and Escaping in wordpress, but i'm not sure the best way to do this, should i do this at the beggining, when i obtain the user input..or i should do it every single time i want to use this data(inlcude when i use echo,etc). for example here

```
<?php   //variables
            $author = sanitize_text_field(get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'author', true )); 
            $link = esc_url(get_permalink());
        ?>
        <?php if($count < $pars_limit || $pars_limit==0): ?>
        <div class="col-md-<?php echo $col;?>">
            <div class="img-wrap">
                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it. ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $link;?>">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('full');?>
                    </a>
                <?php else : ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $link;?>">
                       <?php
                echo '<img src="' . plugins_url( '/asset/images/default.jpg', __FILE__ ) . '" > ';
            ?>
```

here i satinize the varialbes at the beginning, should i do that again whith the echo's??  thanks!

Comment: One generally sanitizes input that they cannot trust. I bet you could search for "sanitize PHP input example" and get exactly what you are looking for -- or at least enough to bootstrap your knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

When you are saving any data to database before saving it, you have to sanitize the input data for safety. You can use wordpress default sanitize methods like `sanitize_text_field()` , `sanitize_email()` etc.

```
<?php  $title = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['title'] ); 
       update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'title', $title );  ?>
```

Here you will find all list of default wordress sanitize methods [wordpress sanitize methods](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/theme-security/data-sanitization-escaping/)

When you are going output any data at frontend then you have to escape the output data to make it more securely display

```
<?php echo esc_html( $title ); ?>

<img src="<?php echo esc_url( $user_picture_url ); ?>" />
```

You see in the above example i use `esc_html()` for outputting a php variable and `esc_url()` for escaping url.

Here you will find all list of default wordpress escaping methods [wordpress escaping methods.](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/security/securing-output/)